# A question on Vitali convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $(X,\mu)$ be a measure space. Vitali convergence theorem says that if

(a) $\mu(X)\lt \infty$

(b) $\{ f_n \}$ is uniformly integrable

(c) $f_n \to f$ a.e.

(d) $|f(x)| \lt \infty $ a.e.

then $f\in L^1$ and $f_n \to f$ in $L^1.$

It is not difficult to prove this, but what if the condition (d) is omitted? I tried to construct a counterexample, but I couldn't. Would you please give me one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\mu$ be a Dirac mass at $x=0$ in $\mathbb{R}$. Let $f(0) = \infty$ and $f(x) =0$ otherwise. Define $f_n(x)= n \chi_{\{0\}}$. It is clear that $\{f_n\}$ is uniformly integrable, for if $\epsilon>0$, take $\delta = 1/2$. Then, if a Borel set $A$ has $\mu(A)<\delta$, it must be that $\mu(A) = 0$ (the Dirac measure assigns only the value 0 or 1). Hence, $\int_A |f_n|\,d\mu = 0 < \epsilon$. We also have that $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ as $n\to \infty$, and $\mu(\mathbb R)=1<\infty$. But $\int_\mathbb{R} f\,d\mu = \infty$, so $f\notin L^1(\mu)$.